# Merging raster without add nodata value

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, nodata

I was trying to merge 2 DEM raster using QGIS raster - merge.

Is there any way to not add nodata to the merged raster?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include in the question some details, like with what tool you want to do it. You are asking about *any way to not add nodata*; so, how are you merging them in a way that nodata is being added?

Comment: As @GabrielDeLuca says, what software are you using? precisely what steps have you tried? What are the NoData values for your inputs and output? Is the (apparent) sea set to the NoData value and all you need to do is set the NoData value in the output?

Comment: You can try including, in the _Additional command-line parameters [optional]_ field, the `-a_nodata none` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure not to check the box next to "No data value".

[image]

Comment: when untick the "No data value" I still get the result as the second figure in the question.  PS. I assume you are using an older version of QGIS? Cause in the latest version (v3.8.3) you can't uncheck the box

Comment: @Roy What is your ultimate objective? The merged output will always have at least the minimum bounding area composed of pixels (i.e. you can either display the pixel values or "hide" them as NoData).

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I want to cut cross-section form the merged DEM.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer: QGIS version 3.22.0**

You can use the `merge` function `raster` -> `miscellaneous` -> `merge`. Then, make sure that you specify the no data value for your input raster and for the output raster. For my case, `-9999` was the no data value from the input raster.

[image: Merge function]

You can get this information from the properties section of the raster.

[image: raster info]